# How to run Redis docker container for Mac Silicon?

Tags: docker, redis, dockerfile, arm64

Looking at the Redis image, https://hub.docker.com/_/redis,  it says that it supports Arm64. However when I run the image on a Mac M1, it shows an `AMD64` warning badge (i.e. poor performance due to Rosetta emulation)

How do I specify the ARM64 version of redis?

Here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM redis:alpine
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY conf/redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
EXPOSE 6379
```

Here's the warning:
[image]

I'm running this on an M1 Mac.

Comment: How did you build the Dockerfile? Is the image you're running public?

Comment: @BMitch The image is not public. The Dockerfile is built using `docker-compose` (if I've understood your question correctly).

Answer (score 8):

You should use `arm64v8/redis` instead of the default. So, replace:

```
FROM redis:alpine
```

For:

```
FROM arm64v8/redis:alpine
```

More info here:
https://hub.docker.com/r/arm64v8/redis

Alternatively, you can use the `--platform` arg or use the `TARGETPLATFORM`, as explained here:

https://nielscautaerts.xyz/making-dockerfiles-architecture-independent.html

Comment: This is a separately built image, though, not the official one. There are different support models

Answer (score 0):

> ```yaml
> FROM redis:alpine
> WORKDIR /usr/app
> COPY conf/redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
> EXPOSE 6379
> ```
>
> The Dockerfile is built using docker-compose

You haven't deployed the multi-platform redis image. You've deployed your own image built from that, and `docker-compose build` doesn't create multi-platform images. If you build it locally on your M1, it should be an ARM64 image. If you want to build multi-platform images, then I'd switch to building with:

```bash
docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64,linux/arm64 -t gitlab.netbuilder.io:5050/... .
```

You can inspect the image with commands like (replacing `redis:alpine` with your own image):

```
docker buildx imagetools inspect redis:alpine
```